# How to use generics for the similar methods with different classes

Tags: java, generics

Is there any way to use some generic method to unify below similar methods?

```
public ClassA getInstanceA(String key)
{
   if (instanceAMap.contains(key))
   {
      return instanceAMap.get(key);
   }

   ClassA result = new ClassA();
   instanceAMap.put(key, result);
   return result;
}

public ClassB getInstanceB(String key)
{
   if (instanceBMap.contains(key))
   {
      return instanceBMap.get(key);
   }

   ClassB result = new ClassB();
   instanceBMap.put(key, result);
   return result;
}

public ClassC getInstanceC(String key)
{
   if (instanceCMap.contains(key))
   {
      return instanceCMap.get(key);
   }

   ClassC result = new ClassC();
   instanceCMap.put(key, result);
   return result;
}
```

So, I would like to have only one method for all classes.
In C++ it can be wrapped into macro, but how it can be gracefully done in Java.

Comment: Is it sure that all those classes have an accessible no-arg constructor?

Comment: any reason why your class holds 3 different maps? can you refactor this and have one map?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose No, classes may have any constructors, its just an example.

Comment: @user902383 The key may not be unique for classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of type-erasure of generic types, you can not create a new instance of a generic type at runtime.

If you are using Java 8, you could have the method take a Supplier which gives you a new object. This makes it the caller's responsibility to create the object. You could do this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

public <T> T getInstance(String key, Supplier<T> objectSupplier) {
    if (instanceAMap.containsKey(key)) {
        return (T) map.get(key);
    }

    T result = objectSupplier.get();
    map.put(key, result);
    return result;
}
```

You can then call the method like this:

```
String s = getInstance("String", () -> "Hello World!");
```

Because of the unchecked cast, don't do this afterwards:

```
Integer i = getInstance("String", () -> 5);
```

It will cause a ClassCastException.

**Edit:** Here is a version which creates a new map for each type.

```
Map<Class<?>, Map<String, ?>> maps = new HashMap<>();

public <T> T getInstance(String key, Class<T> type, Supplier<T> objectSupplier) {

    Map<String, T> map;
    if (maps.containsKey(type)) {
        map = (Map<String, T>) maps.get(type);
    } else {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        maps.put(type, map);
    }

    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    T result = objectSupplier.get();
    map.put(key, result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, each of those methods operate on another map, too. This must also be addressed.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Guess we need the map as a parameter as well then.

Comment: Additionally, in pre-Java-8 you can use a type token: `<T> T getInstance(String key, Class<T> type)`. The method implementation can also use this type for producing instances: `type.newInstance()`.

Comment: No, the map can be maintained in the instance where the methods belong. With a type token (see above) you can also get the correct map. If you update your question accordingly, I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose How would you retrieve the correct map using the type token?

Comment: With a `Map<Class<?>, Object> map` and the retrieval `Object instance = map.get(type)`. As the retrieval result is of type `Object`, you must also cast it: `T obj = type.cast(instance)`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose That would remove the String key in the original maps. I guess you could declare a map like this: `Map<Class<?>, Map<String, ?>> maps` and then retrieve the correct map with `Map<String, T> map = (Map<String, T>) maps.get(type);`. However, I think this is starting to get quite ugly.

Comment: You are right, It must be a map and not an object. The rest is true, still.

Comment: Both of your code blocks generate compiler warnings.  There are safer ways to do those things.

Comment: @VGR I know. It's because of the unchecked casts. What safer ways are you thinking about? How would you do it?

Comment: @marstran Thanks! Didn't know about Supplier<T> approach.

Answer (score 0):

A single method solution requires the type to be passed in:

```
private Map<Class<?>, Map<String, Object>> instanceMaps;

public <T> T getInstance(String key,
                         Class<T> instanceType) {
    if (instanceMaps == null) {
        instanceMaps = new HashMap<>();
        instanceMaps.put(ClassA.class, instanceAMap);
        instanceMaps.put(ClassB.class, instanceBMap);
        instanceMaps.put(ClassC.class, instanceCMap);
    }

    Map<String, Object> instanceMap = instanceMaps.get(instanceType);
    if (instanceMap == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown type: " + instanceType);
    }

    Object value = instanceMap.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        try {
            instanceMap.put(key, value = instanceType.newInstance());
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
    return instanceType.cast(value);
}
```

instanceAMap, instanceBMap, and instanceCMap must all be declared as `Map<String, Object>`.  There is no way to retrieve different specific generic types from a single Map or Collection.

Personally, I would not try to force a single method, but would use overloaded methods, which one could refactor into a single private generic method.  This allows instanceAMap to be declared as `Map<String, ClassA>`, and so on for instanceBMap and instanceCMap.

```
private <T> T getInstance(String key,
                          Map<String, T> instanceMap,
                          Supplier<T> constructor) {
    return instanceMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> constructor.get());
}

public ClassA getInstanceA(String key) {
    return getInstance(key, instanceAMap, ClassA::new);
}

public ClassB getInstanceB(String key) {
    return getInstance(key, instanceBMap, ClassB::new);
}

public ClassC getInstanceC(String key) {
    return getInstance(key, instanceCMap, ClassC::new);
}
```

In versions older than Java 8, the above can be written as:

```
private <T> T getInstance(String key,
                          Map<String, T> instanceMap,
                          Class<T> instanceType) {
    T value = instanceMap.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        try {
            instanceMap.put(key, value = instanceType.newInstance());
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
    return value;
}

public ClassA getInstanceA(String key) {
    return getInstance(key, instanceAMap, ClassA.class);
}

public ClassB getInstanceB(String key) {
    return getInstance(key, instanceBMap, ClassB.class);
}

public ClassC getInstanceC(String key) {
    return getInstance(key, instanceCMap, ClassC.class);
}
```

As @user902383 said, it would be useful if you could use one Map to hold all the objects and keys, but obviously that would require a guarantee that no two classes will ever use the same key:

```
public <T> T getInstance(String key,
                         Class<T> instanceType) {
    Object value = instanceMap.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        return instanceType.cast(value);
    }

    try {
        T newValue = instanceType.newInstance();
        instanceMap.put(key, newValue);
        return newValue;
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first example, you lose type information by having an instanceMap with `Object` as the type of the values. In the last example, you use `instanceType.cast(value)` to cast the value. This is no safer than casting the value with `(T) value`. You lose the compiler-warning, but it can still throw ClassCastExceptions. The example with overloading looks nice though.

Comment: @marstran Yes, some casting is unavoidable without the method overloading.  But this way, there are no surprises:  a ClassCastException occurs in an obvious place, if it occurs at all.  On the other hand, when you do unchecked casts, you get ClassCastExceptions *later* in the code, in unexpected places.  For instance, casting a raw List containing Integers to `List<String>` will result in a surprise exception later when you iterate over it or call get(int).